# OMS Is not defined?

Tags: javascript, google-api, instantiation

Upon inspection of my code in developer tools, I am receiving the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: oms is not defined
at map.1.js:94
at create_marker (map.1.js:96)
```

my application isn't mapping points correctly with "oms.addmarker(marker);" however, it is working with regular "markers.push(marker);" so I think it might be down to instantiation which is causing this error if anybody can tell me what needs changing, would be much appreciated.

```js
var markers = []; // To erase markers later
var user_lat = 52.358409; // Random default location
var user_lng = -1.549072;
/*global geocoder*/
/*global google*/
/*global map*/
/*global draggable_marker*/
/*global custom_icons*/
/*global OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier*/
/*global new_lat*/
/*global navigator*/
/*global create_crime_markers*/
/*global new_lng*/
/*global marker*/

function map_callback(){
  // Without var = set to global scope
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var new_location = new google.maps.LatLng(user_lat, user_lng);
  var map_properties = {center: new_location, zoom: 15, mapTypeId: "hybrid", zoomControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM}, streetViewControlOptions:{position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM}};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), map_properties);
  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, { 
    
        markersWontMove: true,   // we promise not to move any markers, allowing optimizations
        markersWontHide: true,   // we promise not to change visibility of any markers, allowing optimizations
        basicFormatEvents: true  // allow the library to skip calculating advanced formatting information
      });
  draggable_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new_location,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: "Drag me",
      icon: "./img/blue_marker.png"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(draggable_marker, "dragend", function(){draggable_callback();});
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event){draggable_callback(event.latLng);});
  draggable_callback(); // Trigger first load
  
       for (var i = 0, len = marker.length; i < len; i ++) {
        (function() {  // make a closure over the marker and marker data
          var markerData = marker[i];  // e.g. { lat: 50.123, lng: 0.123, text: 'XYZ' }
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerData });  // markerData works here as a LatLngLiteral
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) {  // 'spider_click', not plain 'click'
            iw.setContent(marker.title);
            iw.open(map, marker);
          });
          oms.addMarker(marker);  // adds the marker to the spiderfier _and_ the map
          console.log(marker);
        })();
      }
}

function search(){
  var address = document.getElementById("search_box").value;
  if (address != ""){
    geocoder.geocode( {
        "address": address,
        componentRestrictions: {country: "UK"}
      },
      function(results, status){
        if (status == "OK") {
          var loc = results[0].geometry.location
          draggable_callback(loc);
          map.panTo(loc);
        } else {
          alert("Cannot perform search, reason: " + status);
        }
    });
  }
}

function clear_markers(){
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

function create_marker(lat, lng, title){
  var current_lat_lng = lat.toString() + lng.toString();
        (function() {  // make a closure over the marker and marker data
    // Default icon
    var custom_icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi.png";
    if (title in custom_icons) {custom_icon = custom_icons[title];}
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: custom_icon,
        title: title});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) {  // 'spider_click', not plain 'click'
          });
            oms.addMarker(marker);

        })();
      }
  

function draggable_callback(loc){
  if (loc != undefined) {draggable_marker.setPosition(loc);}

  new_lat = draggable_marker.getPosition().lat();
  new_lng = draggable_marker.getPosition().lng();

  console.log(new_lat, new_lng);
  clear_markers();
  create_crime_markers(new_lat, new_lng);
}

function get_my_loc(){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback, error_callback);
  }
}

function success_callback(position){
  var new_location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  draggable_callback(new_location);
  map.panTo(new_location);
  
}

function error_callback(error){
  switch(error.code){
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert("Denied request for Geolocation");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Your location information is unavailable");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("The request to get your location timed out");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      alert("An unknown error in finding your location occurred");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="google_map"></div>
```

```
    var markers = []; // To erase markers later
var user_lat = 52.358409; // Random default location
var user_lng = -1.549072;
/*global geocoder*/
/*global google*/
/*global map*/
/*global draggable_marker*/
/*global custom_icons*/
/*global OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier*/
/*global new_lat*/
/*global navigator*/
/*global create_crime_markers*/
/*global new_lng*/
/*global marker*/

function map_callback(){
  // Without var = set to global scope
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var new_location = new google.maps.LatLng(user_lat, user_lng);
  var map_properties = {center: new_location, zoom: 15, mapTypeId: "hybrid", zoomControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM}, streetViewControlOptions:{position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM}};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), map_properties);
  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, { 

        markersWontMove: true,   // we promise not to move any markers, allowing optimizations
        markersWontHide: true,   // we promise not to change visibility of any markers, allowing optimizations
        basicFormatEvents: true  // allow the library to skip calculating advanced formatting information
      });
  draggable_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new_location,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: "Drag me",
      icon: "./img/blue_marker.png"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(draggable_marker, "dragend", function(){draggable_callback();});
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event){draggable_callback(event.latLng);});
  draggable_callback(); // Trigger first load

       for (var i = 0, len = marker.length; i < len; i ++) {
        (function() {  // make a closure over the marker and marker data
          var markerData = marker[i];  // e.g. { lat: 50.123, lng: 0.123, text: 'XYZ' }
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerData });  // markerData works here as a LatLngLiteral
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) {  // 'spider_click', not plain 'click'
            iw.setContent(marker.title);
            iw.open(map, marker);
          });
          oms.addMarker(marker);  // adds the marker to the spiderfier _and_ the map
          console.log(marker);
        })();
      }
}

function search(){
  var address = document.getElementById("search_box").value;
  if (address != ""){
    geocoder.geocode( {
        "address": address,
        componentRestrictions: {country: "UK"}
      },
      function(results, status){
        if (status == "OK") {
          var loc = results[0].geometry.location
          draggable_callback(loc);
          map.panTo(loc);
        } else {
          alert("Cannot perform search, reason: " + status);
        }
    });
  }
}

function clear_markers(){
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

function create_marker(lat, lng, title){
  var current_lat_lng = lat.toString() + lng.toString();
        (function() {  // make a closure over the marker and marker data
    // Default icon
    var custom_icon = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi.png";
    if (title in custom_icons) {custom_icon = custom_icons[title];}
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: custom_icon,
        title: title});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_click', function(e) {  // 'spider_click', not plain 'click'
          });
            oms.addMarker(marker);

        })();
      }


function draggable_callback(loc){
  if (loc != undefined) {draggable_marker.setPosition(loc);}

  new_lat = draggable_marker.getPosition().lat();
  new_lng = draggable_marker.getPosition().lng();

  console.log(new_lat, new_lng);
  clear_markers();
  create_crime_markers(new_lat, new_lng);
}

function get_my_loc(){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback, error_callback);
  }
}

function success_callback(position){
  var new_location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  draggable_callback(new_location);
  map.panTo(new_location);

}

function error_callback(error){
  switch(error.code){
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert("Denied request for Geolocation");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Your location information is unavailable");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("The request to get your location timed out");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      alert("An unknown error in finding your location occurred");
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see oms in your html header:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.3/oms.min.js">
```